# Scrape Magento website which uses Cookies for "Add to cart"

Tags: php, magento, curl, cookies

I am scraping [this URL](http://www.beautyinzone.net/etude-chocolate-kiss-perfumed-lip-set.html).

I want to scrape quantity of this item.

For that, my strategy is that I will try to add quantity and POST the form until an error appears saying that **"The amount required for "xyz product" is not enough."**

I have tried posting FORM with `file_get_contents();` and `echo` the output, it returns an error page saying that *`Cookies must be enabled in your browser`*

Here is how I am posting

```
    $postdata = http_build_query(
            array(
                'product' => $prod_id,
                'qty' => 5,
                'related_product' => ''
            )
    );

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $result = file_get_contents($action_url, false, $context);
```

I have also tried `cURL` with

$cookieFile = tempnam(null, 'SMS');
        $userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0';

```
    $cookieFile = tempnam(null, 'SMS');
    $userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $action_url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 0);
    $post = array(
        'product' => $prod_id,
        'qty' => 5,
        'related_product' => '');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
```

But still I get error from that site that Cookies should be enabled in browser.

**So my question is how I can add product to cart using PHP?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it with `Guzzle Goutte`

It receives cookies whichever server sends.